# Use different shapes for label and output in Keras for VGG-19

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

So for my project, I am trying to find a good motion compensation model for a moving object(linear motion) in a CT image by feeding it into a VGG-19 model. My input in a series of 19 CT images(1,128,128,19) and I want to use a completely reconstructed image as my label(1,128,128), however, I want my output to be a $V_x$ and $V_y directions of movement(1,2). So I guess obviously the below error is returned

```
ValueError: Shapes (1, 128, 128) and (1, 2) are incompatible
```

Here is my model, I wonder if it is at all possible to have a difference in shape between the labels and the output of the model?

```
model  = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(128,128,19),filters=3,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", 
activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2),strides=(2,2),name="vgg19"))

model.add(Flatten(name="flatten"))

model.add(Dense(512, name="fc1"))
model.add(Dense(2, name = "fc2"))

opti = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opti, 
             loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics= 
             ['accuracy'])
```

Here is my model summary

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_36 (Conv2D)          (None, 128, 128, 3)       516       
                                                                 
 conv2d_37 (Conv2D)          (None, 128, 128, 3)       84        
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_12 (MaxPoolin  (None, 64, 64, 3)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_38 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 64, 64)        1792      
                                                                 
 conv2d_39 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 64, 64)        36928     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_13 (MaxPoolin  (None, 32, 32, 64)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_40 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 128)       73856     
                                                                 
 conv2d_41 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 128)       147584    
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPoolin  (None, 16, 16, 128)      0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_42 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 conv2d_43 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 conv2d_44 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPoolin  (None, 8, 8, 256)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_45 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 256)         590080    
                                                                 
 conv2d_46 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 256)         590080    
                                                                 
 conv2d_47 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 256)         590080    
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_16 (MaxPoolin  (None, 4, 4, 256)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_48 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 512)         1180160   
                                                                 
 conv2d_49 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   
                                                                 
 conv2d_50 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPoolin  (None, 2, 2, 512)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_51 (Conv2D)          (None, 2, 2, 512)         2359808   
                                                                 
 conv2d_52 (Conv2D)          (None, 2, 2, 512)         2359808   
                                                                 
 conv2d_53 (Conv2D)          (None, 2, 2, 512)         2359808   
                                                                 
 vgg19 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 1, 1, 512)         0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 512)               0         
                                                                 
 fc1 (Dense)                 (None, 512)               262656    
                                                                 
 fc2 (Dense)                 (None, 2)                 1026      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 16,749,210
Trainable params: 16,749,210
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: If you want your label to be an image of shape (1, 128, 128), you need to get rid of the flatten layer + dense layers at the top of your model. Flatten will transform your intermediate feature representation into a single dimensional vector (hence flatten). Further you should remove the max_pooling operations as well, as they reduce the height and width of their inputs and you like your models output to be the same height and width as your input if I understood correctly.

Comment: I want my output to be in a (1,2) shape actually, telling the displacement in the x and y directions. As the (128,128) image label is actually the 'correct' image and I would like to tell from the NN how much in each direction the object moved in the CT

Comment: Could you include the rest of the code as well? `model.train()` in particular and the part where you create data and labels. There seems to be a mismatch between model output and labels, thats where the error comes from. Apart form that, you use cross-entropy as loss, which usually would be used for classification problems. To me it seems more like a regression problem, or not?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, because I am trying to use the model to estimate the slope of a vector for movement for each of the 19 images, but I still don't really understand what I would use as labelsfor that.